# Creating console command artisan

Tags: php, laravel

I try to create console command with the help this manual https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-artisan-commands-to-manage-database-records-in-laravel.
It works well. I enter some link that I have this link in my database.

But now I works with api. I have `time_entries` for all `employees`. And with the help api I should to get `time_entries` and save it in database with the help console command.

But I don't understand how to do it at all.

**Model Time Entry**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $project
 * @property int $issue
 * @property string $activity
 * @property string $comments
 * @property int $hours
 * @property int $month
 * @property int $year
 */
class TimeEntry extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];
}
```

**Commands/LinkNew** (but here I have mistake `Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar::Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\{closure}("2022-08-21 08:26:13", "updated_at")`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\TimeEntry;
use App\Services\RedmineAPIService;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class LinkNew extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'link:new';
    protected $description = 'Create a New Link';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $redmineService = new RedmineAPIService();
        $users = $redmineService->getUsersInfo();

        //isset($user);
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $id = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            $project = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            $activity = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            $issue = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            $comments = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);


            if ($this->confirm('Is this information correct?')) {
                $link = new TimeEntry();
                $link->id = $id;
                $link->project = $project;
                $link->activity = $activity;
                $link->issue = $issue;
                $link->comments = $comments;
                $link->save();

                $this->info("Saved.");
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

**RedmineAPIService**

```
    public function getTimeEntriesInfo(int $user_id): array
    {
        $users = self::getAllData('time_entry', ['user_id'=>$user_id]);
        return $users['time_entries'];
    }
```

I don't understand at all how to fix file `LinkNew`. Can you help?

**UPD:**

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $redmineService = new RedmineAPIService();
        $users = $redmineService->getUsersInfo();

        foreach ($users as $user) {             
            $data = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);

            $id = $data['id'];
            $project = $data['id'];
            $activity = $data['id'];
            $issue = $data['id'];
            $comments = $data['id'];

            if ($this->confirm('Is this information correct?')) {
                $link = new TimeEntry();
                $link->id = $id;
                $link->project = $project;
                $link->activity = $activity;
                $link->issue = $issue;
                $link->comments = $comments;
              //  dd($link->getAttributes());
                $link->save();

                $this->info("Saved.");
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

**dd($link->getAttributes());**

```
249 => array:10 [
    "id" => 5369
    "project" => array:2 [ …2]
    "issue" => array:1 [ …1]
    "user" => array:2 [ …2]
    "activity" => array:2 [ …2]
    "hours" => 1.0
    "comments" => "Comment"
    "spent_on" => "2022-05-27"
    "created_on" => "2022-05-27T05:00:19Z"
    "updated_on" => "2022-05-27T05:00:19Z"
  ]
```

Comment: So what is not working, do you get any errors or warning? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Check ```Commands/LinkNew``` I added mistake there

Comment: What do you mean? Add the errors you are getting, with line numbers and so on.

Comment: And I don't understand at all what I heed to add for function ```handle()``` to get data ```id, project, activity, issue, comments ``` from api. In my example I use function ```getTimeEntriesInfo()``` to get this data

Comment: @Cyclonecode I have exception without any  line numbers

Comment: I tried to output ```dd($link->getAttributes());``` before the line ```$link->save();```. I got exactly the data that I'm trying to save. As I understand it, ```$data``` needs to be iterated somehow (see UDP), but I do not quite understand how. Added changes to ```UPD```.